# Magento 2 How to hide payment method when the Basket Subtotal is ZERO

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, payment, zero-subtotal

I want to hide the payment methods when the basket subtotal is "0"

i have few products in my website where price is "0" but the customer has to pay for shipping incase if they want to purchase the product i want to hide all the options for payment methods so there will be no transaction been made. Is this possible

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 There is payment Method "Zero Subtotal checkout".

You just enable it. It will automatically appear when your total is zero and for hiding other payment we you have to do some customization.

Comment: Hi, i have tried that i found the option in Configuration->sales->payment methods
"zero subtotal checkout" 


Enabled = Yes
Title= No Payment information required
New Order Status = "Not sure which one to pick" i picked suspected fraud

but i can still see the payment method when i click checkout

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below in your Model\Payment\paymentMethod.php file

```
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface|null $quote
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAvailable(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null
    ) {
        /*return parent::isAvailable($quote);*/
        return parent::isAvailable($quote) && !empty($quote) && $quote->getGrandTotal() <= 0;
    }
```